# How to reference a method that returns an array and assign a new value to the array?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, reference

I am trying to access an array from a method that returns an array within the same class. I then need to write back to the array for future use. Here is the code so far: ```

````
public int [] unitSelection(){
    int [] selectedUnits = new int[numberCheck()];

    return selectedUnits;

for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxList.length; i++) {
                    if (checkBoxList[i] == e.getSource()) {
                        index = i;
                        unitSelection()[i] = index;
                        export_to_SRF.setEnabled(true);
                    }
```
````

The code "unitSelection()[i]" is supposed to update the array in the "selectedUnits" Array in the "unitSelected" method. I have been reading but cant find anything in relation to referencing arrays of an external method. Thanks in advance

Comment: I am at present getting an empty array returned

Comment: You're getting an empty array because `unitSelection()` returns a new array at every invocation.  Unless that's just a dummy method body for this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxList.length; i++) {
   if (checkBoxList[i] == e.getSource()) {
      index = i;
      int[] x = unitSelection();
      x[i] = index;
      export_to_SRF.setEnabled(true);
   }
```

But I don't think this will do what you want.  `unitSelection()` returns a new array every time, so that won't actually update an array.

Comment: thanks for the response in the end i moved the array and made it public to my class as i am using it in another method as well.